# iOS App Crash when presenting UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uialertcontroller, visitor-pattern

I am getting a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try to present an `UIAlertController` on my ViewController.

This is my code:

```
let controller = UIAlertController(title: "bob", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
controller.addAction(cancelAction)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

I have also tried replacing the `UIAlertController` with a blank `UIViewController()` and I'm getting a very similar stack trace with the crash in the same place.

This is the stack trace.

```
#0  0x00007fff2b13578d in CA::Layer::retain_parent(CA::Transaction*) const ()
#1  0x00007fff2b1455b9 in CALayerGetSuperlayer ()
#2  0x00007fff485813a8 in -[UIView(UIKitManual) superview] ()
#3  0x00007fff485bf1aa in -[_UITintColorVisitor _visitView:] ()
#4  0x00007fff485beb1f in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#5  0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#6  0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#7  0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#8  0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#9  0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#10 0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#11 0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#12 0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#13 0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#14 0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#15 0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#16 0x00007fff485bec06 in _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors ()
#17 0x00007fff485be6d2 in +[_UIViewVisitor _startTraversalOfVisitor:withView:] ()
#18 0x00007fff4854d9db in -[UIView _dispatchTintColorVisitorWithReasons:] ()
#19 0x00007fff4792522a in -[UIPresentationController _enableOcclusion:] ()
#20 0x00007fff47a42124 in -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] ()
#21 0x00007fff47a3e446 in -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations] ()
#22 0x00007fff4856a44f in __63+[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:]_block_invoke ()
#23 0x00007fff4853b7c0 in -[UIViewAnimationState _runAlongsideAnimations] ()
#24 0x00007fff4853a50a in -[UIViewAnimationState pop] ()
#25 0x00007fff485378ce in +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] ()
#26 0x00007fff4856be60 in +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] ()
#27 0x00007fff4856c231 in +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:] ()
#28 0x00007fff4763b3a3 in -[UIAlertControllerVisualStyleActionSheet animateAlertControllerView:ofAlertController:forPresentation:inContainerView:descendantOfContainerView:duration:completionBlock:] ()
#29 0x00007fff47627ac3 in -[_UIAlertControllerAnimatedTransitioning _animateTransition:completionBlock:] ()
#30 0x00007fff4762748f in -[_UIAlertControllerAnimatedTransitioning animateTransition:] ()
#31 0x00007fff47a42cf5 in ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 ()
#32 0x00007fff47b5af7e in +[UIInputResponderController _pinInputViewsForInputResponderController:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] ()
#33 0x00007fff47a42c89 in ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.645 ()
#34 0x00007fff4856a351 in +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] ()
#35 0x00007fff47a42b0f in _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition ()
#36 0x00007fff47924740 in __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.465 ()
#37 0x00007fff4809be5b in _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks ()
#38 0x00007fff4808c7b4 in _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks ()
#39 0x00007fff480bc3a9 in _afterCACommitHandler ()
#40 0x00007fff23bd3867 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#41 0x00007fff23bce2fe in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#42 0x00007fff23bce97a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#43 0x00007fff23bce066 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#44 0x00007fff384c0bb0 in GSEventRunModal ()
#45 0x00007fff48092d4d in UIApplicationMain ()
#46 0x000000010c50ca8b in main at /Users/stephenfurlani/Developer/winterfell/Winterfell/AppDelegate.swift:21
#47 0x00007fff5227ec25 in start ()
```

I have no idea what's going on. `UIAlertController` works fine in other places in my application. It crashes on my iPhone 11 Pro Max 13.1.3, but works fine on my iPhone 11 13.1.3. It crashes if I run everything on the main thread in the `async{}` block.

I will also note that it crashes on the *simulator* for iPhone 11 Pro Max but not the simulator for iPhone 11.

My VC Hierarchy is as follows:

TabBar -tab-> Navigation -root-> TableView -show-> DetailView

The detail view is what is presenting the `UIAlertController`

TabBar -tab-> Navigation -root-> TableView -show-> DetailView -show-> SubDetailView

I can present an AlertController from the subdetail page as shown above.

---

I tried to create a small project to highlight the error, but it works just fine. X( https://github.com/sfurlani/crashingMenuBar

---

None of the answers to these questions help:
 * [display UIAlert will crash the app on present?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58735355/266252)
 * [App crash when presenting UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47176379/266252)
 * [Swift UIAlertController -> ActionSheet iPad iOS8 Crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26039229/266252)

Comment: Is this on iPad?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini no, this is not. I added that comment in my question but it works on iPhone 11, but crashes on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what if you wrap all four lines of code in the `async` closure?

Comment: @JoshuaKaden it still crashes :(

Comment: Check with `message: ""` instead of `message: nil`.

Comment: So strange! If it works in other parts of your app, then it must be something to do with the context. What's different about the presenting controller? Also, just to narrow it down, does a standard alert crater as well, or is it limited to the action sheet?

Comment: @Larme it still crashes if I put text in there or `""`

Comment: @JoshuaKaden it crashes with `.alert` or `.actionSheet`. I'll add details about the presenting view controllers in the question.

Comment: Why do you need DispatchQueue.main.async? Why isn’t your code already on the main thread to start with?

Comment: @matt force of habit. It crashes with or without the `.async{}` block

Comment: Can you create a very minimal github project that reproduces the crash? Clearly it has nothing to do with the tiny code you have shared.

Comment: @matt I tried to create a project, including this i thought might be important like uiappearance and the logic around the menubarbutton - but the project works just fine X( https://github.com/sfurlani/crashingMenuBar

Comment: If it works just fine that's no use to anyone. :)

Comment: Another problem with your question is that you're not telling us enough about the crash. There's some sort of message in the console telling what the problem is, usually; what does it say? Also, if you suspect this is a memory management error, why not try reproducing it with Zombies turned on?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: ever figure this out? i am having this issue

Answer (score -2):

The code you wrote works well on iphone but for iPad action sheet    doesn't appears like iphone. it appears from the UI Element where you    did Tap. so for action sheet to work on iPad

```
       let controller = UIAlertController(title: "bob", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
      let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
      controller.addAction(cancelAction)
  if let presenter = controller.popoverPresentationController {
          // From Bar Button
       presenter.barButtonItem = yourBarButtonItem
  // Comment the above line if you are tapping on some UIElement other than barButton
          presenter.sourceView = yourUIView
     presenter.sourceRect = yourUIView.bounds
  }

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
      }
```

Comment: This is *NOT* running on an iPad. it's crashing on an iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Comment: I already did as I posted in my question that I tried the solution to the iPad questions. It still crashes.